# Can't sent detail in destinationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want send Detail in my destinationViewController.

```
[segue.destinationViewController setDetail:item];
```

http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2014-05/17/x2pu26iznie1.png

But I get the error:

http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2014-05/17/obg25xfg6be6.png

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: You generally want to copy the error text into your question :-)

Comment: http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2014-05/17/obg25xfg6be6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your detail view controller is wrapped in a navigation controller and you aren't navigating through that relationship to set the detail item.

Consider whether you really want to be using a navigation controller and a modal - why aren't you just pushing the detail view controller?

If you want to keep the nav controller then use the `topViewController` to get to the real detail controller.